# How to set a button for a particular selected row enabled?

Tags: angularjs

There is a HTML table in which for every row I am adding SET button:-

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row1</th>
            <th>Row2</th>
            <th>Row3</th>
            <th>Row4</th>
            <th>Row5</th>
            <th>Row6</th>
            <th>Row7</th>
            <th>Row8</th>
            <th>Row9</th>
            <th>Row10</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in array track by $index" ng-class="{'selected': isSelected(row.value1)}" ng-click="selectRow(row.value1)">
            <td>{{row.value1}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value2}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value3}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value4}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value5}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value6}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value7}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value8}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value9}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value10}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" ng-disabled = "setBtnDisable" 
           class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-ng-click="show()">SET</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My angular directive code:-

```
scope.setBtnDisable = true;//Default value
scope.selectedRow = null;//Default value

            scope.selectRow = function(rowID){
                if (scope.isSelected(rowID)){
                    scope.setBtnDisable = true;
                    scope.selectedRow = null;
                } else {
                    scope.setBtnDisable = false;
                    scope.selectedRow = rowID;
                }
            };

            scope.isSelected = function(rowID){
                return (scope.selectedRow == rowID);
            };
```

What I am want to do is, enable the SET button only for that particular selected row and remaining rows's SET button to remain disable. But right now when I click any row all the buttons got enabled. Can anyone tell me solution to enable the SET button for only select row?

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine in your code, since you are using a variable for setting `ng-disabled` in the button, when set to true, it applies to the all the table rows.

**Solution:**

Use the same function for `ng-disabled` but invert the boolean. Thus it will be unique for each row and you will get the desired result! Like so.

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!isSelected(row.value1)" 
class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-ng-click="show()">SET</button>
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Hi  your problem i think is the setBtnDisable cuse it is one for ALL your rows ..

what if you try something like:

```
    scope.setBtnDisable = [array.length];
scope.setBtnDisable.forEach(function(item){
item = false;
});
    scope.selectedRow = null;//Default value

                scope.selectRow = function(rowID){

                        scope.setBtnDisable[rowID] = !scope.setBtnDisable[rowID] ;
                        scope.selectedRow = null;

                };

                scope.isSelected = function(rowID){
                    return (scope.selectedRow == rowID);
                };
```